# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char - {U+2010)

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I am encountering the following error and have no idea where to find the solution;

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ‐ (U+2010)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.129   boundedness and actor‐
                                network theory.
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

[32] [33]) [34]
\openout2 = `chapters/abbreviations.aux'.
```

Can anybody aid me in finding the solution? I am using ShareLatex if that is necessary information.

Comment: Your character here (`‐`) is not a hyphen but a Unicode dash : replace it with a normal hyphen.

Comment: Is it clear from this error message where this is? it refers to output.bbl, line 129 not to a page or lne in the coding

Answer (score 7):

Recent LaTeX versions declare the symbol U+2010 (DASH) in `utf8enc.dfu`, `t1enc.dfu`. The former is loaded by default. The declaration can be given
explicitly for older LaTeX installations:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2010}{-}% support older LaTeX versions
```

Versions with U+2010:

- `utf8enc.dfu`: 2016/02/28 v1.1s
- `t1enc.dfu`: 2016/02/28 v1.1s
- LaTeX 2016/03/31

Comment: I'm having this problem, but my `pdflatex` is pretty current. At what version was this fixed?

Comment: @ryanjdillon I have added the version numbers. The LaTeX version is relevant, but not the version number of pdfTeX.